# How to find the memory map of a device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I would like to know where in the linux source code should i search for finding the board specific packages, more clearly, the memory map of different devices.

I was browsing through the link : http://lxr.linux.no

Thanks

Comment: To be more clear, I just want to know if it is possible to retrieve such information from the kernel..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a PCI device, lspci -vvv  will show you.

You can also check /proc/iomem and /proc/ioport for memory and port mappings, respectively.

Comment: Looks like `/proc/ioport` is a typo. Should be `/proc/ioports`.