# How to change U-Boot memory map

Tags: linux, embedded, bootloader, u-boot

The U-Boot(2009.03) on MS104-SH4 has the RAM memory map shown below.

0x8c000000 Not for use (4kB)
0x8c001000 for Linux kernel & root file system (3MB)
0x8c400000 for Linux process (28MB)

For me, 3MB for Linux kernel & root file system is too small because
Linux kernel & ramdisk has 1MB and 3.5MB respectively. So I'd like to
change above memory map, for example like shown below.

0x8c000000 Not for use (4KB)
0x8c001000 for Linux kernel & root file system (16MB)
0x8cf60000 for Linux process (16MB)

In my guess, I have to modify uboot source code, but cannot find where
I should modify. Does somebody tell me if it is possible to modify u-boot memory map?
If yes, please also tell me how to do it. Thanks for your help!

I found a similar question on [How to find the memory map of a device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185338/how-to-find-the-memory-map-of-a-device), but my SH4 iomem is empty (0 size) so looks like other topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to modify U-boot memory map. you need to modify source code of U-boot .`U-boot/include/configs/<board_name.h>` is the place where you can configure memory map . where `<board_name.h>` is your architecture specific file and has `#define` entries which you can change to desirable values. `u-boot/arch/<architecture_name>/lib/board.c` perform the memory map initialization.